# Open POPUP window with previously set height and weight by user

Tags: javascript, swing, internet-explorer, window.open

I am using two application. One is Java Swing application and other is web application. From the Swing application, I am opening Web Application in Internet Explorer.Cant use any other browser.

```
Process p = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start iexplore.exe  \"" + url + "\"");
```

where url is URL of web application.

Requirement is to open browser without addressbar,menubar,toolbar etc. I cannot use kiosk mode. Browser should not open in maximized mode. So I have created one intermediate page that opens actual page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var title="IINkIT";
var a = window.self;
var b = a.open('\login.jsp?id=<%=id%>', title, 'channelmode=no, toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=0, resizable=1, copyhistory=0');

if(b != null) {
  var parentWindow = this.window;    
  parentWindow.open('', '_self', '');      
  parentWindow.close();  
}
</script>
```

This opens the required page as popup window as required.
Now the issue, if user resizes this window or adjusts window at particular position than when next time user opens this web application from Swing application. It should open with that set height and width at that position only. If I do not use this intermediate page, and directly open main mage IE preserves the position and height width. But in this case, all address bar,status bar etc are enable. Is there any other way to achieve both these requirements.